# usage of `#[pallet::constant]` vs `const associated item`

Tags: rust, constants

I can have config of my pallet in two different ways:

```rust
trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    // *--snip
    #[pallet::constant]
    SomeConstant: Get<u32>,

    const ANOTHER_CONSTANT: u32,
}
```

So when do I define it with `#[pallet::constant]` and when as `associated item`

Comment: So what specifically is your question? What is the difference here if any? Or when to use one over the other?or...?

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs, using the macro gives you the extra benefit of having it included in the metadatas:

> To put Get associated type into metadatas, use the attribute #[pallet::constant], e.g.:
>
> ```rs
> #[pallet::config] 
> pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {      
>   #[pallet::constant]         
>   type Foo: Get<u32>; 
> }
> ```

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#palletconstant

You can see the full definition and implementation of this constant macro here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/constants.rs#L20-L108